# How to retrieve the images from a MySQL database using JSON in Android

Tags: php, android, json

I am get the JSON data from PHP. And pass to Android.

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
   mysql_connect("localhost","root","MobixMySQL");
   mysql_select_db("cozydine");
   $q=mysql_query("SELECT itemimage from fooditem");
   while($obj=mysql_fetch_object($q)){
       $arr[]=$obj;
   }
   echo '{"names":'.json_encode($arr).'}';
   mysql_close();
?>
```

And here is how I read the image:

```
try {
    BufferedReader reader =
        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
    is.close();
    result = sb.toString();
    jArray = new JSONObject(result);
    JSONArray json = jArray.getJSONArray("names");
    for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        JSONObject e = json.getJSONObject(i);
        Qrimage=e.getString("itemimage");
        System.out.println(Qrimage);

        byte[] qrimage = Base64.decode(Qrimage.getBytes());

        System.out.println(qrimage);
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(qrimage, 0,qrimage.length);
        ImageView imageview=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        imageview.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Here is how I parse the response from the PHP code:

```
codeInputStream is = null;
String result = "";
JSONObject jArray = null;
try {
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(serverurl+"showall.php");
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    is = entity.getContent();
} catch (Exception e) { }
```

In that way I can view only the last image on my Android mobile... I want display all images from the database into the Android mobile. How can I get all images using JSON data?

Comment: This is insufficient information. we need to know more about the services the php code provides and what responses you get from them. What is `Qrimage`? What is `e` here: `Qrimage=e.getString("itemimage")`

Comment: <?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","MobixMySQL");
mysql_select_db("cozydine");
 
$q=mysql_query("SELECT itemimage from fooditem");
while($obj=mysql_fetch_object($q)){
$arr[]=$obj;
}
echo '{"names":'.json_encode($arr).'}';
mysql_close();
?>
the above code my php code

Comment: Please modify your question with elaborations like this. Also you still have not provided the java side code: the logic of constructing this `e` of yours.

Comment: my java codeInputStream is = null;
  String result = "";
  JSONObject jArray = null;
  try {
   HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
   HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(serverurl+"showall.php");
   HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
   HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
   is = entity.getContent();
  } catch (Exception e) {
   }
  here connect with server i can provide code  please see i don't how to modify i am new for stack over flow please help me in android

Comment: this is my response to the server          try {
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
     is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   String line = null;
   while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line + "\n");
   }
   is.close();
   result = sb.toString();
   jArray = new JSONObject(result);
  JSONArray json = jArray.getJSONArray("names");
   for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
 HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
   JSONObject e = json.getJSONObject(i);
Qrimage=e.getString("itemimage")

Comment: You can edit your own question by clicking the edit button below it. There you can format the strings you paste here. Otherwise they are VERY hard to understand. Allow me to help you with that...

Comment: is means input stream object ,Qrimage is string

Answer (score 2):

Low you've got quite a complex code there. However, I think your problem is very simple: you actually get all the images, but in those two lines:

```
ImageView imageview=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
imageview.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

You overwrite the prevoius picture with the next one to come. Thus only the last one is displayed eventually. You can easily check that by changing the for cycle to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < json.length() - 1; i++) {
```

Then the second to last image should be shown. If this really is the case you will need to make out a way to display all the images simultanously.

I just couldn't find any other problem in your code, but please if I got it wrong, write back so I can try to help more.

**EDIT** As for how you can display the images together: you use image gallery. The image gallery is just another type of android widget (like the image view).

In your activity do the following few lines (initialize your gallery):

```
try {
    BufferedReader reader =
        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
    is.close();
    result = sb.toString();
    jArray = new JSONObject(result);
    JSONArray json = jArray.getJSONArray("names");
    Gallery g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
    g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, json));
```

Here I use image gallery adapter which I define as follows:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ImageView[] mImages;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context, JSONArray imageArrayJson) {
        this.mImages = new ImageView[imageArrayJson.length];
        String qrimage;

        for (int i = 0; i < imageArrayJson.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject image = imageArrayJson.getJSONObject(i);
            qrimage = image.getString("itemimage");

            byte[] qrimageBytes = Base64.decode(qrimage.getBytes());

            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(qrimageBytes,
                                                0,
                                                qrimageBytes.length);
            mImages[i] = new ImageView(context);
            mImages[i].setImageBitmap(bmp);
            mImages[i].setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 100));
            mImages[i].setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        }
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mImages.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return mImages[position];
    }
}
```

And you need to declare this image gallery in the layout of your activity:

```
<Gallery xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/gallery"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

Hopefully this all will help you, however, I have written it in text editor, without trying, so it might be that I made some error. If so please write back.

**EDIT2** If you want to stack the images vertically just use `ListView` instead of the gallery. You will still need to set the adapter, but you can use the same one I already provided you with. However, keep in mind that the `ListView` will not necessarily show the images one by one.

Comment: ya sir what u told exactly correct i get previous image in my emulator for using your for loop. i want display all images in my emulator .. please help m

Comment: I was afraid of this... Ok I will try this give me few moments

Comment: sir i want to display all images in my emulator please say the possible solution for me

Comment: i try your given code but it show  error in log cat like this  error in parsing data.java.lang.class exception:android.widget.image in logcat error please tell me how to solve this error

Comment: So you got it working? :) Now comes the time to pay back with an accept and upvote, please :)

Comment: i am getting the images in galary view like horizantally, now i want display the images one by one like vertically...

Comment: You see the 0 just next to top of my answer? The up arrow is upvote. It means you find my answer valuable and well structured. Next to the zero you see empty check. If you click it you accept my answer as answering your question. You can do both if you feel like it is the case.

Comment: I added one more edit, that will hopefully help you in getting it vertical.

Comment: I am changed gallery instead of list view but hear mImages[i].setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 100)); here how can modify this one for listview .. i want see all images in listview vertically

Comment: I am replace in gallery to list view.. run the application it show view error .. please i want see all images into a listview

Comment: I am sorry SO questions are not meant to serve for series of questions. We need to close this one at some point. If you need further assistance ask another question.